# View that display single node which has id the same as last part of url (from last / to the end)

Tags: views, theming, uri

I have an urls:

- website.com/portfolio-entries/23
- website.com/portfolio-entries/25

I would like to make an view for them to display node which has id the same as last part of url (from last `/` to the end).

I have red the description for View > Url (administration panel > Content > Views > My_view):

> This view will be displayed by visiting this path on your site. You may use "%" in your URL to represent values that will be used for contextual filters: For example, "node/%/feed". If needed you can even specify named route parameters like taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term

So I set it to `portfolio-entries/%entry_id` (I hope I understood it right).

But how now make this view display only sinlge entry which has the id set to `%entry_id`?

I've tried with View > Filters (add) > ID but I can only set there hard-coded values (e.g. 23 makes this view display only entry #23). How can I place there my `%entry_id`?

In other words I was reproducing steps from https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/views-specific-node/ (it's for Drupal 7 but it works the same way in Drupal 8) **but instead of har-coding the id value I want to take it from last part of the url.**

Answer (score 0):

Normally the parameter is not named, it is a single % without name:

```
portfolio-entries/%
```

The example `node/%/feed` is also a single % in the middle part of the url. The third part of the url is a fixed `feed`, so that only urls with a `/feed` at the end will match.

To use this parameter for filtering you need to set a contextual filter in the advanced settings. If you only have one parameter, this filter will automatically get this, when selecting the field you want to filter.